# How to use the same query which has the random value after I click next button

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Now the problem is I have that query

```
var question = _repository.tbl_TestQuestion
    .Where(x => x.nCourseId == courseId && x.nChapterId == chapterId && x.bActive == true)
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
```

when I click the next button to the next question it random the query again  I don't need to random again I just need it to select from the 10 questions that already I random it

so any help

Comment: *the next button*, *the next question* .... when, how? We only see a list of questions in a random order. Not any code that apparently executes some navigation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check a `Session` in the 'Page_Load` of the page. If it does not exist create a new Guid, otherwise get the Guid from the Session.

```
public string myGuid;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["guid"] == null)
    {
        myGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Session["guid"] = myGuid;
    }
    else
    {
        myGuid = Session["guid"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the Guid anywhere on the page.

```
var question = _repository.tbl_TestQuestion
    .Where(x => x.nCourseId == courseId && x.nChapterId == chapterId && x.bActive == true)
    .OrderBy(x => myGuid).Take(10).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

It seems ordering by a `Guid` stored as a variable does not work `.OrderBy(x => myGuid)`. Not even when parsing the `myGuid` variable `.OrderBy(x => Guid.Parse(myGuid))`.

You can either store the entire `tbl_TestQuestion` as a Session after the initial sorting an re-use that or sort the questions randomly when loading them from the Database (if you use one)

```
public _repository.tbl_TestQuestion questionList;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["question"] == null)
    {
        questionList = _repository.tbl_TestQuestion
            .Where(x => x.nCourseId == courseId && x.nChapterId == chapterId && x.bActive == true)
            .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();

        Session["question"] = questionList;
    }
    else
    {
        questionList = Session["question"] as _repository.tbl_TestQuestion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the var question query doesn't random with the orderBy(x => myGuid)

Comment: when I use orderBy(x => Guid.New())  it random , but when use orderBy(x => myGuid) it doesn't random

Comment: thank you for your gold effort helping me , your last updated is working, I appreciate your help THx VDWWD

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the two answers above:

- Check if the session GUID exists, (as in answer #1)
- if so, then access/return the Enumerable stored in the session
- if not, then generate/store the new session GUID, then create/store the enumerable (as in answer #2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store your enumerable in a Session ?

```
        IEnumerable<tbl_TestQuestion> question = _repository.tbl_TestQuestion
            .Where(x => x.nCourseId == courseId && x.nChapterId == chapterId && x.bActive == true)
            .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();

        Session["SessionQuestions"] = question;
```

The you can use it again to access a the other question.

Comment: How to made the value for the session constant , as everytime he will run the question query and will change the value of the session , I need to fill the value of the session just in the first time